# How to query a LUBM ontology?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, lubm

How to query a LUBM ontology(extracted form given univ-bench.owl. given on the official site using generator) to find how many university it contains?

Comment: What? Have you generated the dataset or just the ontology? Using a SPARQL `COUNT` query doesn't work for you? How are your SPARQL skills? Have you walked thorugh any SPARQL tutorial so far? Which triple store do you use?

Comment: And "how many universities" doesn't make any sense for the LUBM benchmark. The benchmark generator takes the number of universities as mandatory input parameter.

Comment: That is true "The benchmark generator takes the number of universities".If i forget this then what is the another option to count it.

Comment: Load the data into a triple store and write a SPARQL `COUNT` query

Comment: no its not working

Comment: WHAT is not working?

Comment: please write a proper query to fetch universities

Comment: Please, tell me **what is not working**? Which triple store do you use? Why is it no option to learn SPARQL? You're trying to benchmark triple stores, I don't know why. What is the use case?

Comment: I have extracted LUBM benchmark by some university which i don't know, now using Jena to store triples and want to know through "how many universites are there in a LUBM ontology"

Comment: The documentation of aggregates in SPARQL is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates). There you can find how to write a `COUNT` query. And I don't understand why you can't rerun the dataset generation with the number of universities that you need. It's a matter of seconds/minutes to generate the data.  Even the file names can indicate the number